# Import frames from a video

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using `MediaPlayer` to open a video and `DrawingContext.DrawVideo()` to get a specific frame from a video source.

The problem is that I can't know if the MediaPlayer is positioned at the right place.

`Therad.Sleep(500)` is a hack.

Is there another easy way of getting frames from a video source? Or should I start looking for a `DirectShow` solution?

Comment: There's a somewhat elderly but potentially useful implementation of frame grabbing with a MediaPlayer here: http://dlaa.me/blog/post/8921665 .

Comment: Thanks, that's a start, now I need to make this available as a simple method call: `GetFrameRange(TimeSpan time)`

Comment: Done! Post your comment as an answer so I can edit with my details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a somewhat elderly but potentially useful implementation of frame grabbing with a MediaPlayer here:

[dlaa.me/blog/post/8921665](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/8921665)

Here is the simple structure of the media grabber:

```
LoadVideo();
//Add event handler to the Changed event.
GetFirstFrame();
//Change video Position.
//When the Changed event fires: 
GetCurrentFrame();
```